# Mongodb : Find objects using multiple conditions

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is probably a very basic question but I am find difficulty to get it properly. I want to find all objects which "logdate" is between a date range and which "status" is inactive.

This is my data looks like:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59c359b310c4af1b68e4175f"),
        "instanceId" : "53871505974705410",
        "socketId" : "jZWhIjVP6eCfrCy5AAAO",
        "FName" : "",
        "MName" : "",
        "LName" : "",
        "userToken" : "",
        "EmailId" : "",
        "MobileNo" : "",
        "status" : "inactive",
        "logdate" : ISODate("2017-09-21T06:18:27.181Z"),
        "EnteredName" : "Raj"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59c366ff5601022638484dbc"),
        "instanceId" : "515421505978110987",
        "socketId" : "vk-dB-b0GLxpj0b5AAAD",
        "FName" : "",
        "MName" : "",
        "LName" : "",
        "userToken" : "",
        "EmailId" : "",
        "MobileNo" : "",
        "status" : "active",
        "logdate" : ISODate("2017-09-21T07:15:11.823Z")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59c88824651d770ec46b95d7"),
        "instanceId" : "22631506314272112",
        "socketId" : "ceS0MPxaB78eXTdMAAAC",
        "FName" : "",
        "MName" : "",
        "LName" : "",
        "userToken" : "",
        "EmailId" : "",
        "MobileNo" : "",
        "status" : "inactive",
        "logdate" : ISODate("2017-09-25T04:37:56.868Z"),
        "EnteredName" : "abir"
}
```

and this is my query:

```
var isoStartDate = 2017-09-24T18:30:00.000Z
var isoEndDate = 2017-09-24T18:30:00.000Z
db.collection(config.db.userDetailsCollection).find({logdate: {$gte:isoStartDate, $lt: isoEndDate}},{"status": "inactive"}).toArray()
```

any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var queryObj = {};

if (req.query.from_date && req.query.to_date) {
    var date = {};
    var fromDate = new Date(req.query.from_date);
    var toDate = new Date(req.query.to_date);
    date.$gte = fromDate;
    date.$lte = toDate;
    queryObj.logdate = date;
}

queryObj.status = "inactive";

db.collection(config.db.userDetailsCollection).find(queryObj,function(err,result));
```

Comment: Thanks its working but have one problem. Suppose i want to search todays record means fromDate : 25-09-2017 and toDate: 25-09-2017 then no result found. but if I select toDate : 26-09-2017 than the desire result comes. any idea?

Comment: you send with time means from date time 00-00-00 and to date time 23-59-59

Comment: can you please update that in your answer. That's help me to understand better.

Comment: you send like this moment('25-09-2017').format('YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00Z');

Comment: it's my pleasure

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the brackets mixed up. Change

```
db.collection(config.db.userDetailsCollection).find({logdate: {$gte:isoStartDate, $lt: isoEndDate}},{"status": "inactive"}).toArray()
```

to

```
db.collection(config.db.userDetailsCollection).find({logdate: {$gte:isoStartDate, $lt: isoEndDate}, "status": "inactive"}).toArray()
```

and see if it works.